# How to disable autocorrect in IE10?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-10, autocorrect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable spell checking in Internet Explorer 10 (Windows 8)](https://superuser.com/questions/439517/disable-spell-checking-in-internet-explorer-10-windows-8)

I installed the IE10 beta on Windows 7. It has an annoying autocorrect feature like the one in MS Word that messes up everything I write. How do I disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open IE10, then go to *Tools » Internet Options » Programs*.
- Click on the *Manage add-ons* button
- Select *Spelling Correction*
- At the bottom of the screen, Uncheck *Enable spelling correction*
- Click on the *Close* button to close the *Manage add-ons* screen
- Click on the *OK* button to close the "Internet Options" screen.

Now you can type without being bothered by auto-correction!