# How do I disable spell checking in IE 11 (Win 8.1)?

Tags: windows-8, spell-check, internet-explorer-11

My issue is similar to the one mentioned here: [Disable spell checking in IE 10/11 (on Windows 7, 8, 8.1)](https://superuser.com/questions/439517/disable-spell-checking-in-internet-explorer-10-windows-8)

I am using  Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit

---

What I've tried already:

**Deactivating the spelling options:**

From the following, [borrowed screenshot](https://superuser.com/a/480566/137286) from the old Windows 8 (my interface is German, therefore I couldn't create one myself), I have turned both options off and restarted IE.  It's still "correcting" my texts.

[image: PC Settings]

**Searching for 'spelling correction' addons:**

The indicated option in the following [borrowed screensnot](https://superuser.com/a/508953/137286) does *not* exist on my PC.
[image: IE Addons]

Is there any way of disabling it? I prefer a canonical solution if one is available. If not, I am also interested in registry hacks or other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this issue is a permissions issue.  When running IE in EPM mode, regkeys are being blocked at location HKCU\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7 due to ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES not being added to permissions.  So a way to fix this (please respond if this does not work), is to go to

1. Win key
2. type "regedit" and click on the regedit application
3. Navigation to HKey_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7
4. Right click on the 1.7 directory
5. Select "Permissions..."
6. Click Add
7. Click Advanced
8. For Locations choose your computer
9. Click Find Now
10. Select ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES and click OK

A fix will be coming down, but in the meantime, this is correct fix

Comment: Your solution worked beautifully, thanks! It would be nice if you could post the link to the fix once it becomes available!

Answer (score 6):

From [How to Disable Built-in Spell Checker Feature](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-built-in-spell-checker-feature-in-internet-explorer-10-ie10/) :

1. Move your mouse cursor to top-right or bottom-right corner of screen to access Charms Bar and click on **Settings** option.
2. Now click on **Change PC settings** option given at the bottom.
3. It'll open Metro Control Panel or PC Settings page. Click on **General** section given in left-hand side in Windows 8. If you are using Windows 8.1, click on **PC & devices -> Typing**.

   [image]
4. Now in right-side, turn off following 2 options:
   Autocorrect misspelled words
   Highlight misspelled words
5. That's it. It'll disable spell checker feature in Internet Explorer as well as the whole operating system.

Comment: It's really strange because they are already turned off on my system, but IE keeps correcting my texts.

Comment: Is it happening on both desktop and modern versions of IE11?

Comment: Yes, it's happening on both versions.

Comment: Have you tried IE safe mode?

Comment: Do you mean `iexplore.exe -extoff`? It shows the same behavior.

Comment: This looks like a bug in IE11. Well, there is maybe the very strong-arm method [described here](http://dottech.org/89729/windows-8-how-to-turn-off-spell-check-and-autocorrect-on-pc-or-tablet/). Create a system restore point first.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I've found [this comment](http://dottech.org/89729/windows-8-how-to-turn-off-spell-check-and-autocorrect-on-pc-or-tablet/comment-page-1/#comment-1003942) on the linked site. I now changed the Language Settings to a US American spelling with a German keyboard layout. I don't get any unwanted corrections anymore (at least when I'm writing English). (Regarding your answer, I want to wait whether someone can post another solution which isn't that radical as propsed in your link.)